# How to mock RestSharp portable library in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, moq, restsharp

I would like to mockup the RestClient class for test purposes

```
public class DataServices : IDataServices
{
    private readonly IRestClient _restClient;


    public DataServices(IRestClient restClient)
    {
        _restClient = restClient;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUserByUserName(string userName)
    {
        User user = null;

        // create a new request
        var restRequest = new RestRequest("User", Method.GET);
        // create REST parameters
        restRequest.AddParameter("userName", userName, ParameterType.QueryString);
        // execute the REST request
        var restResponse = await _restClient.Execute<User>(restRequest);
        if (restResponse.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            user = restResponse.Data;
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

My test class :

```
[TestClass]
public class DataServicesTest
{
    public static IRestClient MockRestClient<T>(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string json)
    {
        var mockIRestClient = new Mock<IRestClient>();
        mockIRestClient.Setup(x => x.Execute<T>(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
          .Returns(new RestResponse<T>
          {
              Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json),
              StatusCode = httpStatusCode
          });
        return mockIRestClient.Object;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async void GetUserByUserName()
    {
        var dataServices = new DataServices(MockRestClient<User>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "my json code"));
        var user = await dataServices.GetUserByUserName("User1");
        Assert.AreEqual("User1", user.Username);
    }
}
```

But I can't instantiate the `RestResponse` object, I've the following error:

```
.Returns(new RestResponse<T>
{
    Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json),
    StatusCode = httpStatusCode
});
```

> Cannot access protected internal constructor 'RestResponse' here.

How can I workaround this ? I'm using the FubarCoder.RestSharp nuget package on a Xamarin portable Library.

Comment: Mock `IRestResponse<T>` and return that

Answer (score 25):

Mock `IRestResponse<T>` and return that

```
public static IRestClient MockRestClient<T>(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string json) 
    where T : new() {
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)
    var response =  new Mock<IRestResponse<T>>();
    response.Setup(_ => _.StatusCode).Returns(httpStatusCode);
    response.Setup(_ => _.Data).Returns(data);

    var mockIRestClient = new Mock<IRestClient>();
    mockIRestClient
      .Setup(x => x.Execute<T>(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
      .ReturnsAsync(response.Object);
    return mockIRestClient.Object;
}
```

The test should also be updated to be async as well

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetUserByUserName() {
    //Arrange
    var client = MockRestClient<User>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "my json code");
    var dataServices = new DataServices(client);
    //Act
    var user = await dataServices.GetUserByUserName("User1");
    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("User1", user.Username);
}
```

Comment: @Nkosi I tried to use your method and I get following error: 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'RestClient.Execute<T>(RestRequest)'. Do you have an idea why I am getting this?

Comment: @alminh As the error message explains, chances are that you are using a type that is abstract.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I needed to add constraint where T : new() on the MockRestClient method. It works fine now.

Comment: @alminh you are correct. I reviewed the source code on Github and realized that the constraint was missing. I've updated answer to reflect that change.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any great answers so I ended up writing a helper library. I published it to NuGet - MoqRestSharp.Helpers. This project is aimed to help unit test RestSharp as it extends Mock so this helped me test my RestSharp requests and response error handling.

It uses Moq

- [NuGet Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoqRestSharp.Helpers/)
- [Repository Link](https://github.com/ZinkNotTheMetal/Moq.RestSharp.Helpers) - Examples are in the project too

Feedback is always welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Complete solution

```
using Moq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NUnit.Framework;
using RestSharp;
using System.Net;

namespace RestMockTest
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var client = MockRestClient<User>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "{\"Name\":\"User1\"}");
            var restRequest = new RestRequest("api/item/", Method.POST);
            var restResponse = client.Execute<User>(restRequest);

            var user = restResponse.Data;

            Assert.AreEqual("User1", user.Name);
        }

        public static IRestClient MockRestClient<T>(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, string json)
            where T : new()
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
            var response = new Mock<IRestResponse<T>>();
            response.Setup(_ => _.StatusCode).Returns(httpStatusCode);
            response.Setup(_ => _.Data).Returns(data);

            var mockIRestClient = new Mock<IRestClient>();
            
            mockIRestClient
              .Setup(x => x.Execute<T>(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()))
              .Returns(response.Object);
            
            return mockIRestClient.Object;
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```