# Mocking the api client generated by Swagger Codegen

Tags: c#, moq, swagger-codegen

I generated the C# client using swagger-codegen. Currently I am writing a wrapper around that client and would like to have unit tests around my logic. However I am trying to figure out how can I mock the calls to the generated clients. I am using a Moq framework. I am trying to use the code from [How to mock RestSharp portable library in Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646830/how-to-mock-restsharp-portable-library-in-unit-test) to mock the RestClient. However I am unable to figure out how to inject RestClient into the generated client.

Comment: Show an example of your clients and how they depend on RestClient. Lets see if we can figure out the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi The RestClient is used by the code that was generated by the Swagger Codegen: for example you can generate something similar using https://gist.github.com/databus23/848f60539956284e504605d4d9c01bc1 and running codegen with following parameters "java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i swagger.yaml -l csharp"

Comment: Can you include one of the classes you want to test in your question so we can use that to show you how to test it

Comment: @Nkosi let's say there is none at this point. For now I am trying to figure out how to replace the calls to the remote api. This is why I am trying to inject mocked RestClient to simulate different errors. For now let's say my class has a property of type MyClient and a constructor that is initializing that property. As the parameter constructor can take a RestClient to inject mocked restclient. Everything else doesn't have much to do with testing.

Comment: Then the linked post in your question already has what you are asking for.

Comment: @Nkosi, no it doesn't. That code does not produce the restclient that is accepted by the generated ApiClient.

Comment: Then again I am asking you to include an example of the ApiClient so that I know what you are referring to.

Comment: Basically the code that is in the linked question when trying to cast it to RestClient that is required by the generated client produces runtime exception Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.IRestClientProxy' to type 'RestSharp.RestClient'.

Comment: That is because the example code is using the interface abstraction of the client and not the implementation. If the generated code uses the implementation them I would suggest refactoring to use the abstraction.

Comment: Which means either having the same refactoring applied to the client every time it is regenerated or having a custom template for the client generation. Both of this things I was trying to avoid and though that RestClient could be mocked fully vs the interface.

Answer (score 2):

The generated swagger client will be a partial class.
Add a partial class for the client and extract the method you want to mock.
Let's assume you want to Mock the Get by id method.

```
public interface IApiClient
{
    Task<Item> GetItemByIdAsync(int id);
}

public partial class swaggerClient: IApiClient
{
    
}
```

On your test code you'll have to mock using the interface:

```
var mock= new Mock<IApiClient>();
mock.Setup(r => r.GetItemByIdAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
      .ReturnsAsync((int id) => new Item(id));
var client = mock.Object;
```

Happy testing!

Comment: My mocking is complex. I now need to take the, mocked per above, `IApiClient` and pass it into a service that is expecting `ApiClient` - no go. I tried `Mock<IApiClient> mock = new Mock<ApiClient>();` and it's not having it the way you can normally create a concrete class and assign to an interface variable. Any ideas or work arounds you can think of?  Thanks in advance!